# Merging two result sets

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I know there are a number of questions here relating to what I am facing, but none of them are able to solve my situation.

I have two tables **TABLE_1** and **TABLE_2**.

Table **TABLE_1** has columns:
 ID,
 NAME

Table **TABLE_2** has columns:
 CODE,
 AMOUNT,
 QUANTITY

The two tables have a different number of columns but the row count is same.

Is possible to write an SQL query wherein I can retrieve all the columns from both the table in a single result set. 
I am working on MySQL server.

**Note**: Both the tables have no common column. Any help is appreciated.

This is how I wish to retrieve:

```
| ID  |  NAME  |  CODE   | AMOUNT  | QUANTITY |
|     |        |         |         |          |
|     |        |         |         |          |
|     |        |         |         |          |
```

Comment: do you want to create the table with row_count^2 or the same number of rows? Without using a where clause will result into a cross join wherein the number of rows in the first table is multiplied by the number of rows in the second table.

Comment: @anonyXmous I wish to have the same number of rows. No cross join.

Comment: @anonyXmous Also both the table have the same number of rows.

Comment: If there is no common column, look to see if you have any other tables you can link through.  You may find that `table_1` has a relationship with `table_x` which has a relationship with `table_y` which has a relationship with `table_z` which has a relationship with `table_2`.  If you can't do that, then you're in trouble.  SQL data has ***no*** inherent ordering.  There is no real concept of "the first row", so there is is no real way the line up the rows with each other in a consistent, deterministic or logically coherent manner.

Comment: @MatBailie; the question has no logical explanation except combining the tables. It is not even fits to the term 'merge' since there is no logic involve except that they both have the same number of rows and different column names.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below query

```
SELECT a.ID, a.NAME, b.CODE,b.AMOUNT  ,b.QUANTITY 

FROM (SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name ASC) AS RowNo, * FROM TABLE_1 )a

inner join (SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  CODE ASC) AS RowNo, * FROM TABLE_2 )b 
On a.RowNo= b.RowNo
```

Comment: On what justification should "the first name" necessarily be joined to "the first code"?  You've also made an implicit assumption that those columns are unique in their respective tables.

Answer (score 0):

@Allan, here is my solution. Hope it helps.

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
ID INTEGER,
NAME VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE t2(
CODE  INTEGER,
AMOUNT INTEGER,
QUANTITY INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(91, 'Name1');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(92, 'Name2');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(93, 'Name3');

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1, 123, 2);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(2, 233, 4);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(3, 433, 1);

Query:
SET @rank=0;
SET @rank2=0;

select id,name,code,amount,quantity
from 
(SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, id, name
from t1) a,
(SELECT @rank2:=@rank2+1 AS rank, code, amount, quantity
from t2) b
where a.rank=b.rank;
```